# Output formatting column and row

Tags: xml, formatting

I have a large xml file and I am able to extract the data from it, but my issue is that it is all listed underneeth eachother and basicly I look at a way to get the output for the same field in a different entry at the same row.

I'm looking for a way to get the data listed in one row with several columns rather than 2 columns with many repeating rows.

This is the code I use:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="ENTRY">
    <html>
      <body>
        <table border="1">
          <xsl:for-each select="ENTRY">
            <xsl:if test="@CLASS='Role'">
               <tr bgcolor="LightBlue">
                 <td><strong>Role</strong></td>
                 <td><xsl:value-of select="@NAME"/></td>
               </tr>
               <tr bgcolor="lightblue">
                 <td><strong>Modified</strong></td>
                 <td>
                   <xsl:for-each select="ATTRIBUTE">
                     <xsl:if test="@NAME='Date Last Modified'">
                       <xsl:value-of select="VALUE"/>
                     </xsl:if>
                   </xsl:for-each>
                 </td>
               </tr>

/ More Custom actions /

            </xsl:if>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </table>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
```

The output I get is:

```
 Role     Administrator
 Modified 1375737186
 / more data
 Role     Agent 
 Modified 1375736772 
 / more data
 Role     Allow Prompt Recording 
 Modified 1375477004 
 / more data
```

What I am after is an output like this:

```
 Role     Administrator    Agent        Allow Prompt Recording
 Modified 1375737186       1375736772   1375477004
 / more data
```

What would be the best approach for this?

Ultimately I would also like to be able to create a export file that can be imported in Excel with the same information the page provides, but I haven't looked into that yet.

Thanks!

Comment: Please add an example for your input data.

Comment: xml data can be found here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/u1egi2wctmazjuf/roles_20130812.zip

Comment: Has anyone some ideas?